# Quiero utilizar jquery en angular 5 pero me sale el siguiente error¿Como soluciono esto?

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular5, vscode

[image]

Quiero utilizar jquery en un archivo typescript pero al momento de compilar me sale el error en la imagen adjunta!! abro la consola del navegador y no hay errores. Estoy usando visual studio code. Por favor ayudenme

Comment: Tienes instalado las definciones para jQuery? Si no, las puedes instalar asi `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

Comment: Otra opción, es usar `window.$` (o `global.$` que es lo mismo)

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo, trata de agregar tu código en modo texto en lugar de como imagen (igual para el mensaje de error), eso hace más fácil encontrar el problema (p.e. otro usuario con tu mismo error no encontrará tu publicación porque el error está como imagen y no se puede buscar). Además, deberías [edit] la pregunta para añadir algo más de información (¿dónde y cómo incluyes jQuery en tu proyecto?). Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu archivo `typescript` tienes que declarar una variable antes de `@component({...`

```
declare var $:any;
```

Y tienes que poner en tu `index.html` tu archivo `jquery`

Ejemplo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```